# Should very old questions be updated to newer standards?

Tags: discussion, tags, edits, title

For example I am often [Removing "tags" from the title of questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles).

Now I see a question like [CSS: How to make background-image above background-color in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8491958/css-how-to-make-background-image-above-background-color-in-a-list) that clearly falls into this category but is actually quite an old question.  Is it appropriate to update these question's title?

Comment: Great stuff - I see so many outdated questions and am happy to hear that you are helping out keeping things up to date. That's why SO is just such a great resource, with relevant information to be found.

Comment: ~900 answers, 3953 cast votes and 2119 posts edited.. I'm doing more to maintain then directly helping people at this point... but I feel like I'm helping either way.

Comment: Maintaining is definitely helping, nothing worse than trying an accepted answer and realising it's completely wrong or outdated after a few hours. Your Karma should increase :)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Yes, it's appropriate to improve questions no matter what age they are. Site standards change over time, and we want old questions with good answers to be improved to meet those standards.

---

Regarding the specific kind of change you're making, i.e., removing tags from titles, I'd be sure to leave the tag in when it's important to the question. Just reword it to make it a question. For example, you might title that particular question "How to make background-image above background-color in a list using CSS?" rather than simply removing the tag.

Comment: That trailing "using CSS" is redundant is it not

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes, in this particular case it is, but I wanted to stick with the same example.

Comment: But Bill, sticking with the same example made it seem as though titles like the one in this example should always be edited to retain the tag in the rewritten title.

Comment: @JohnSaunders "when it's important to the question" People can use their own judgement.

Comment: BTW Bill, thanks for all your generosity and helpfulness.

Comment: How strange it is to see Bill's name with no diamond next to it...

Comment: @ArtOfCode Trust me, that's nothing compared to how strange the site looks to me right now. ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I don't think it's redundant.  Most people visit older questions via search engine, we should be encouraging titles to contain the most appropriate keywords to help those users find that question.  There's a big difference between "how do I loop over a list" and "how do I loop over a list in LanguageX".  It doesn't help that, particularly on CSS questions, users tend to tag the question with tags that are completely unrelated to the problem (javascript, html, sass, etc.).

Comment: @cimmanon: The search engine aspect is handled. `CSS` is in the meta keywords.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It may be in the meta keywords, but it doesn't necessarily stand out in the list of entries you read. When possible, the title should make it as clear as possible what the question is about, even if some of it is redundant with some of the content of the question or its tags: that's the purpose of a title (on StackExchange and elsewhere).

Comment: @Bruno: That's a good reason to talk about displaying tags underneath titles in lists of questions (they already are in most cases). It's not a good reason to talk about butchering titles to add redundant and unindexable information! (Read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/190747/155739)) See, that's the beauty of naming the technologies in tags _not_ the title: the SO devs may change where and when they are displayed with the flip of a switch!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit What I'm saying is that you don't control how other sites can link to the question. It is very natural to link to a question using its title, be it in a search engine result or an external article of some sort. I agree tags are useful (and should be there too), but titles are still the first human readable entry point to a question. A good title should be sufficiently descriptive (including which language or frameworks are at the centre of the question).

Answer (score 2):

I would have left that question alone, for two reasons:

- Although `css` is both in the tags and in the question title, it is very relevant for bringing scope to the question. The title is the first thing the reader will see (especially when coming from external sources), and a good title should be as descriptive as possible within reasonable length. (You have indeed kept CSS in the title anyway.)
- Some users sort their question feeds by activity. Such a minor change bumps up this question at the top of their feeds for no real benefit. Changing "*CSS: How to make [...]*" into "*Use CSS to make [...]*" is really nitpicking, but it makes people who follow this topic check this question's history to see what has been changed, when nothing really has.