# project-euler is back as projecteuler

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

[project-euler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/project-euler) [recently got burninated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275935/burninate-project-euler), but is back as[projecteuler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/projecteuler)
Can we kill this before it gets more than the handful of questions it already has?

Comment: SO has over 50,000 posts about project Euler.  None of them properly tagged anymore, an excellent way to get the exact same questions about the exact same project problem asked over and over again.  Of course it keeps coming back.

Comment: Not sure I disagree with you, but the community decided to get rid of the tag, and so we should get rid of the variants also. Of course, if we get the same question over and over, we should be closing as duplicate in any case. Having a tag for project euler wont solve that.

Comment: Hmm, "community" isn't very accurate.  The tag was destroyed by a posse from the Python chat room.  Press the buzzer if you know why Python programmers don't like questions about program that emphasize speed.

Comment: Well, one should also read the gem of a tag-excerpt which is preserved on that burninate-request. Paraphrased: "Don't answer when you answer." Also, there are more questions dealing with that: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=euler+is%3Aq

Comment: @HansPassant: If you need speed to solve Project Euler problems, you are not solving them correctly.

Comment: @HansPassant are you implying that SO users who also talk in the Python chat room are not part of the community?

Comment: @HansPassant A user not affiliated with the room made the request, the meta community agreed with it, and we used both the chat room and the meta post to organize our efforts.  The merits of Python did not factor into it.

Comment: @davidism I think was Hans is referring to is that this is one of the measure that has been adopted after some discussions by a small subset of users: those who've seen the discussion on Meta. Many of these are then branded as "adopted by the community" whereas it was probably decided after a discussion between 0.001% of the community. Agreed, those who don't vote partly lose their right to complain, but not everyone has the time to spend following every argument on Meta.

Comment: It's not possible, in any online community, to involve "everyone" in any given decision.  For instance, in the 2015 election, we had [nearly 150,000 active eligible voters](http://stackoverflow.com/election/6), but only 27k actually voted.  In this case, the meta post was prominently visible and no one was trying to "hide" anything.  That's good enough in my book.

Comment: @Kevin Of course, that's good enough. I'm just saying there's a lot of little rules where a something relatively minor is suddenly banned for whatever reason (some I would support, some I wouldn't, that's not relevant), and then people say: that's the way it's been decided, it's set in stone, that's it now. (E.g. discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30039639/372643), partly related to [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/292281/372643): people sometimes nitpick for not much, which generally makes SO less enjoyable...)

Comment: @HansPassant: I'm a Python programmer; questions which emphasize speed are fine by me; and I don't like how a vocal minority passes for a "community decision", I only just found out about it. In any case I think there's a case for a sister site "Programming Challenges".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've removed the tag of both questions.

Next time, just suggest an edit to have the tag removed, if it's only a handful of questions.