# What to do about the question "Simple example of threading in C++"

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

The question [Simple example of threading in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266168/simple-example-of-threading-in-c) came to my attention a few days ago following on from [this edit suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23744063). While the edit suggestion was rejected by myself and one other as it did not add anything of value to the question, it seems that there is now a debate as to whether this question should be re-opened or not.

At the time of writing this post the question has 2 re-open votes (from the current [reduced threshold](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388313/experiment-closing-and-reopening-happens-at-3-votes-for-the-next-30-days-until?cb=1) of 3), and has been through the reopen queue seven times ([timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/266168/timeline), [1](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/21544963), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/21616728), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/21685113), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/21838009), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/22264111), [6](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/22318425), [7](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/23744887)) with a consistent decision to leave the post closed.

I'm of the opinion that the question should remain closed as Too Broad by current standards as there doesn't seem to be [any prior research on the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users/261593#261593), and that there are a large number of solutions that could satisfy this request. However I am **not** advocating the deletion of the question as it has historical value (+390 and 640k views) and to my knowledge is the target of a number of duplicate questions.

Personally I am in favour of a historical lock, but I'd like to open a discussion about this question and how it should be handled.

Comment: Too broad?, is a simple threading example in c++ so hard that you can't fit in an answer?. Prior research that is a down vote reason, not a close reason and considering that the question is 10 years old, I would say it's part of current research effort (you can't apply that rule).

Comment: Tangentially related: [Should very old questions be updated to newer standards?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292170/should-very-old-questions-be-updated-to-newer-standards) - Questions should ideally be held to the current standards of the site regardless of age, and improved where possible. If someone made an edit that brought it up to modern SO standards without invalidating the answers, then I'd happily reopen

Comment: @yivi I'm not a c++ guy, but I think the scope is fairly good (if not maybe it can be edited in), How many different way can you do threading in c++ (with the current scope) are there really 1000 ways?. Is it not enough to protected that question instead. I can't see how you can't fit an answer in the answer box, nor can I immagine that there are infinitive ways of doing threading in c++. Do note slightly changes to code is hardly another example (since then this rule would be valid for any "How do I" question)

Comment: [Why do 'some examples' and 'list of things' questions get closed?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7538/31260) (SE.SE meta guidance on questions like that)

Comment: @RobertHarvey I noticed you've put the lock on the question. Is that just for the duration of this discussion, or your final decision based on what's been discussed here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The question itself is badly written from the time when SO was far less strict. In addition, at the point when it was asked C++ only had custom, non-standard thread libraries: pthread, Win API, boost etc. So some answers might be outdated.

But what it boils down to is if the post as whole is valuable and meaningful to preserve. The number of up-votes on one answer suggests as much. Essentially the top-voted answer is a "hello world" about C++ threading, which is valuable to have somewhere on the site. So we shouldn't close this.

I suggest that we rather petition for it to get "historical lock" status. Meaning that the question isn't a good example of the kind of questions we allow on the site, but the thread as whole is valuable to preserve. This will lock all edits and voting too, however.

Answer (score 7):

It seems that what is too broad has changed at some point in time.  The too broad reason used to have

> There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

And the *There are either too many possible answers* would qualify the question for being too broad.

This is no longer the case though.  Too broad now has

> Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

And on [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) it also adds

> too broad - if your question could be answered by an entire book, or has many valid answers (but no way to determine which - if any - are correct), then it is probably too broad for our format

Which to me means that this question is okay as even though it can have many answers, we are capable of determining which ones are correct.

All in all, I would say as the site is now, it would be okay to have this question open.  We can use it canonical for the many how to thread questions we get.  Being able to add new answers would also allow other users to add new solutions as the standard library grows/matures.

Comment: even if;  *There are either too many possible answers*, would that actually fit?, How many ways can you do threading in c++ with current scope?

Comment: @PetterFriberg The question is not scoped to just using standard C++ so that would allow any C++ thread library, which is where I see the many answers coming from.  There are at least Qt and OpenMP that get a lot of use.  There are probably others out there as well.

Comment: I'd argue the scope is the problem. There's several valid ways of doing threading without the stdlib, one of which is boost::thread. There's also other threading libraries as Nathan mentioned. But, AFAIK (disclaimer: I'm a C++ noob), the stdlib only has std::thread and std::async. Then there's posix/windows threads as well, but they're platform-specific